# Multiplayer Android Game-doubts about database online

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, multiplayer

I developed a stupid game in eclipse (not using any particular library such as libgdx, only with "normal code").
I have some doubts about the multiplayer and databases online. In my game I haven't developed yet a database. So i thought I should have create a database online with mysql and connect to my android app. If so i would create users stored in my mysql online and the parse them with a json parser connecting to mysql trough some php based bridges.
Then i searched for android multiplayer and i found out that a more efficient way to create login user is using google+ login offered by google. 
Gived the fact that my database isn't only a way to let user log in but it is also a way to store tha stats about their matches, If i wanted to use g+ login, should I have a mysql database connecting to my app to store other data, or in a way that i actually ignore google provides these things?

The other doubt is about multiplayer: what i should do to implement it?
Once the g+ login is implemented, then what should I implement?

Matches between users are managed and stored completely by google or not?

Should I have to add these informations in my DB online (if at the point one the DB is needed).

Sorry for my bad english.
Hope you can help me.
Thank you.

Comment: I dont know if it was clear: my first doubt is if I used google+ login and the services about multiplayer eoffered by google, should I have my own mysql db running on my server? if so how do I integrate it and the services offered by google?

Comment: the game is a stupid tic toe online: i want to create online just to understand how to.